# How can I import a svg file to a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js

In vue single file component. I import a svg file like this:

```
import A from 'a.svg'
```

And then how can I use `A` in my component?

Comment: what do you need it for? tons of information is lacking here

Comment: This question is not Vue specific, as it depends on the webpack loader you use to load your SVG files. What do you want to achieve with that import statement? Do you want `A` to be a String containing your SVG file? Do you want to inline or simply include `a.svg` in your template? Do you simply want to ensure that `a.svg` is available in when your component is inserted? Please extend your question with use case, the relevant parts of your Vue Component, and the relevant parts of your webpack configuration.

Comment: Not only is it not Vue specific, it's not Webpack specific...

Answer (score 55):

Based on the information you provided, what you can do is:

1. Install vue-svg-loader

`npm install --save-dev vue-svg-loader`

2. Configure webpack:

```js
module: {
    rules: [
      {
       test: /\.svg$/,
       loader: 'vue-svg-loader', // `vue-svg` for webpack 1.x
      },
    ],
  },
```

3. Import the svg and use it as a regular component:

```js
<template>
  <nav id="menu">
    <a href="...">
      <SomeIcon class="icon" />
      Some page
    </a>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import SomeIcon from './assets/some-icon.svg';

export default {
  name: 'menu',
  components: {
    SomeIcon,
  },
};
</script>
```

Reference: https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader

Comment: This solution is really nice. However, it took me a while to figure out two things: 1. if you are using vue CLI 3.x, you need to create a vue.config.js file to modify the webpack config as described in https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader#vue-cli and 2. If you are using TypeScript, you also need to declare a svg module, as also described in the docs: https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-to-use-this-loader-with-typescript

Comment: Great tool - using it I however faced an `Invalid Component Definition` - but quickly found the reason in https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/issues/1

Comment: Installing an npm package doesn't help understand how it works.

Answer (score 48):

I've gotten the following to work in Vue 3. Doesn't require messing with webpack or installing any third party plugins.

```js
<template>
  <img :src="mySVG" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      mySVG: require('./assets/my-svg-file.svg')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Note**: I'm aware that you cannot modify certain pieces of the SVG when using it in img src, but if you simply want to use SVG files like you would any other image, this seems to be a quick and easy solution.

Comment: If you want to use an image just as is - then you even don't need to require it at all. Just do `<img src="@/assets/my-svg-file.svg" />`.

Comment: Not true, at least not in all cases. In Vue 3, vue-cli 4.5.2, `npm run serve` delivers SVGs with content-type "text/html" and the image does not show.

Answer (score 35):

If you have control over the svg file, you can just wrap it in a vue file like so:

`a.vue:`

```
<template>
  <svg>...</svg>
</template>
```

Just require the file like this afterwards: `import A from 'a.vue'`

Comment: are there any downsides to this approach, besides having to wrap every SVG if you have a ton?

Comment: If you have a lot of svg files you should probably load them "properly" with a loader as @renato-krcelic suggests.

Comment: Also, if you have a lot of svg files, this will add significantly to your app's loading time, because instantiating vue components doesn't come for free. This is especially relevant in Vue 2, less so in Vue 3.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Webpack you can use the require context to load SVG files from a directory. Be aware that this will put all SVG files within your Javascript files and might bloat your code though.

As a simplified example I am using this `svg` component:

```
data() {
    return {
        svg: ''
    };
},

props: {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}

created() {
    this.svg = require(`resources/assets/images/svg/${this.name}.svg`);
}
```

The template simply looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div :class="classes" v-html="svg"></div>
</template>
```

Normally you can't simply load SVG files like that and expect them to be used with a `v-html` directive since you are not getting the raw output. You have to use the Webpack `raw-loader` so make sure you get the raw output:

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'raw-loader',
            query: {
                name: 'images/svg/[name].[ext]'
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'svgo-loader',
            options: svgoConfig
        }
    ]
}
```

The example above also uses the `svgo-loader` since you will want to heavily optimize your SVG files if you do down this route.

Hopefully this help you or anyone else out on how to solve this without diving straight into a third-party solution to fix this.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use something like this:

```
<template>
  <img :src="logo"></img>
</template>

<script>
import logo from '../assets/img/logo.svg'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      logo
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This doesn't require installing external modules and works out of the box.

Comment: Note you can not affect the properties of a svg ( fill / stroke ) if you use it as an image src. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695560/how-can-i-import-a-svg-file-to-a-vue-component

Comment: True, but some people just need this. I just needed this.

Answer (score 7):

I would just use [vue-svg](https://github.com/sam3d/vue-svg)

**Install** via Vue CLI 3:

```
vue add svg
```

**Input:**

```
<img src="@/assets/logo.svg?data" />
```

**Output:**

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,..." />
```

or this is work also...

```
import LogoImage from "@/assets/logo.svg?inline"
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to use pug as a template engine (comes with many advantages) - if you do so, you will be able to easily include files like SVG's just by writing:

```
include ../assets/some-icon.svg
```

That's it! there is nothing else to do - I think this is an very easy and convenient way to include stuff like smaller svg's - file's easily included code is still clean!

Here you can get some more information how to include PugJS into you Vue instance https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-pug

Comment: Where would you put that include? I'm confused because it looks like something that would be part of the javascript... but if that's the case you haven't shown the pug markup?

Comment: Just have a look at the PugJS documentation, there it is documented how to do it:

https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html

Answer (score 2):

First you need a specific loader for the component which will contain the svg
my webpack.base.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'vue-svg-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,

        use: [
                    {
            loader: "vue-loader", 
            options: vueLoaderConfig
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "vue-svg-inline-loader",
                        options: { /* ... */ }
                    }
                ]
      }
//.. your other rules
}
```

docs of vues-svg-inline-loader : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-svg-inline-loader

docs of vue-svg-loader : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-svg-loader

Next, you can initialise a vue file

```
<template>
<div>

  <img svg-inline class="icon" src='../pathtoyourfile/yoursvgfile.svg' alt="example" />

</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'



export default {
  name: 'logo',
  data () {
  },
  }

</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
#logo{
  width:20%;
}
.rounded-card{
    border-radius:15px;
}
//the style of your svg 
//look for it in your svg file ..
//example
.cls-1,.cls-7{isolation:isolate;}.cls-2{fill:url(#linear-gradient);}.cls-3{fill:url(#linear-gradient-2);};stroke-width:2px;}..cls-6{opacity:0.75;mix-blend-mode:multiply;}.cls-7{opacity:0.13;}.cls-8{fill:#ed6a29;}.cls-9{fill:#e2522b;}.cls-10{fill:#ed956e;}.cls-185{fill:#ffc933;}..cls-13{fill:#ffd56e;}.cls-14{fill:#1db4d8;}.cls-15{fill:#0f9fb7;}.cls-16{fill:#3ad4ed;}.cls-17{fill:#25bdde;}.cls-18{fill:#fff;}
//


</style>
```

Your svg fils must dont contain style tag so copy paste the style in the vue style with scoped propoerty to keep it specific to this component

you can just load you component in specific place of your app 
and use it

```
<template>

<v-app id="app">

    <logo/>
   <router-view/>

</v-app>



</template>

<script>
import logo from './components/logo.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      //your data
    }
  },
  components:{
logo //the name of the component you imported
  },


  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {

  font-family: 'Hellow', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #070b0f;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Vite and not Webpack: [Solution 2 from this article](https://dev.to/geowrgetudor/dealing-with-svg-icons-in-vue-vite-an9) worked great for me with Vue 3 inside Astro.

1. Install `vite-svg-loader`.
2. Add to Vite config:

```
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    // ...
    svgLoader(),
  ],

});
```

or for Astro:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

import vue from '@astrojs/vue';
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    vue(),
  ],
  vite: {
    plugins: [vue(), svgLoader()],
  },
});
```

3. Define component for convenience:

```js
<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const icon = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`./icons/${props.name}.svg`));
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="icon" />
</template>
```

4. Use:

```
<template>
  <Icon name="foobar" />
</template>

<script>
import Icon from './Icon.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Icon,
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I knew if I scrolled far enough I would find a Vue 3 & Vite answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can always save it as a .svg file in your `/static/svg/myfile.svg` (using webpack) and just use it as an image file: `<img src="/static/svg/myfile.svg">`. No require / import / loader needed.

Comment: doesn't work if you want to interact with the SVG with css classes or `fill:currentColor`

Answer (score 0):

+1 for [@Stephan-v's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552239/1114901), but here's a slightly modified approach for 2021 with Webpack 5.

1. Your Vue component `<template/>`

Option A: Single SVG file

```
<template>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <use :xlink:href="require('@/assets/icons/icon.svg')"></use>
  </svg>
</template>
```

Option B: SVG Sprite (e.g. for FeatherIcons)

```
<template>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <use
      :xlink:href="require('@/assets/icons/sprite.svg') + `#${iconName}`"
    ></use>
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    // Dynamic property to easily switch out the SVG which will be used
    iconName: {
      type: String,
      default: "star",
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

2. You may need a Webpack loader.

NOTE: You may not need the Webpack Loader if you're using Vue 3 (as mentioned above) or Vite. If you're using Storybook or Nuxt, you will likely still need it.

```sh
$ npm install svgo-loader -D
```

```sh
$ yarn add svgo-loader -D
```

`webpack.config.js` (or similar)

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./foo.js",
  output: {},
  // ... other config ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      /////////////
      {
        // Webpack 5 SVG loader
        // https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/
        // https://dev.to/smelukov/webpack-5-asset-modules-2o3h
        test: /\.svg$/,
        type: "asset",
        use: "svgo-loader",
      },
    ],
    /////////////
  },
};
```

4. Done!

Comment: I'm using vite, what is the syntax for this:

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get svgs loading inline via

```
<div v-html="svgStringHere"></div>
```

Where `svgStringHere` is a computed property that returns an svg as a string

Answer (score -1):

My favourite approach is to create an SVG Vue component and then use it wherever I need it. The good thing about this is that you can add encapsulated custom styles to the SVG to fit your needs.

### So, how to set it up ?

1. Create a Vue component:

```
<template>
</template>
    
<style>
</style>
```

2. Add the SVG code in the template.. It may look something like this....

```
<template>
   <svg
      width="314"
      height="318"
      viewBox="0 0 252 213"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
        .....rest of code....
    </svg>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

3. Add style and the class attribute to the SVG

```
<template>
   <svg
     class="custom"
     width="314"
     height="318"
     viewBox="0 0 252 213"
     fill="none"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   >
          .....rest of code....
   </svg>
</template>

<style>
  .custom {
     -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -20px);
     transform: translate(-30px, -20px);
  }
</style>
```

4. Use your SVG component in another component (this is just an example, make sure you import from the proper directory)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MySvg />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import MySvg from "@/components/MySvg.vue";
</script>
```

**Note:** you can add `scoped` to the `<style>` tag in case you don't want to leak CSS styles to other components in your app.