# VueCompilerError: Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are ignored in client component templates in SVG case

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuejs3

I understand that normally the script and style tag must not be in **temlpate** part of Vue component, but that about **svg** content? The below SVG has been drawn by Illustrator; the `cls-1` class has not been created manually.

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1 {
                fill: none
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I has been told:

```
VueCompilerError: Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are ignored in client component templates.
  at D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\YamatoDaiwaFrontend\FrameworksIntegrations\Vue\Package\Source\SVG_Icons\MapAndLocation\MapIcon__Clock.vue:1:67
  1  |  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><defs><style>.cls-1 {
     |                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  2  |    fill: none
     |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

No solution except rewriting of generated SVG code without classes?

Comment: It's best practice to extract `<style>` tags. ```<style scoped> .class-N(1, 2 ... n) { ... }</style>```, if there's some interactivity put them into separate `<script>` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use <style> inside of inline svg while using vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324182/can-i-use-style-inside-of-inline-svg-while-using-vue-js)