# Configure Vue-SVG-Loader in Vue.config.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vuejs2

I'm using Vue/cli version 4.2.2 and I downloaded the vue-svg-loader, I was following the accepted answer here [How can I import a svg file to a Vue component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695560/how-can-i-import-a-svg-file-to-a-vue-component) and according to the comments, I have to configure vue.config.js but I could not find how exactly I should configure it.

Current these are the contents of my vue.config.js file:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    'style-resources-loader': {
      preProcessor: 'scss',
      patterns: [
        "./src/styles/global.scss"
      ]
    },
    svgLoader: {
      svgo: {
        plugins: []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is an empty array where I suppose I need to add something, though I have no idea what...

**EDIT:**
In addition to the marked answer, I had to follow these steps: [Unable to import svg files in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717164/unable-to-import-svg-files-in-typescript) <- The first answer && I got the code from https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-to-use-this-loader-with-typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure webpack to use vue-svg-loader, something like this should work:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'vue-svg-loader'
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

As stated in [vue documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration):

> The easiest way to tweak the webpack config is providing an object to the configureWebpack option in `vue.config.js`

PS: make sure you have vue-svg-loader as dependency on your project.

Comment: I followed this but I get "cannot find module" when I try to import an SVG as a component

Comment: I had to also add `chainWebpack: config => { config.module.rules.delete("svg"); }` - See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140937/5924962